# How to add a white space between two numbers -Regex.Replace()

Tags: .net, regex

Someone knows how to add a white space between two number when they do not have an space. So I have `#,###,##` and want `#,## #,##`

I have this:

```
2.100.000,000,04
300,450,06
23,011,87
54.845,37462.521,21
```

I want this:

```
2.100.000,00 0,04
300,45 0,06
23,01 1,87
54.845,37 462.521,21
```

In order to see if a replace should occur I did this expression `\,([0-9]{3})\,`

Thanks for your help.

**Update 1**

- Number format could be `#.###.###,##` (always with two decimals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace occurrences of `(,\d{2})(\d,)` with `$1 $2` (the `$1` and `$2` are references to the capturing groups, depending on the language or tool you may need to use `\1 \2` instead).

Comment: The second number could in fact be longer than 1 digit. View this example: http://regex101.com/r/zI0vT9 (view the last line). You can see why it fails in the debugger here: http://regex101.com/r/zI0vT9/#debugger. You don't have to do much to fix this, merely change `\d,` to `\d+,`. See here: http://regex101.com/r/sR4fW6

Comment: You are right. Also the thousands separator must be added (if any) http://regex101.com/r/vA4mS8

Comment: Yeah I had made an assumption based on the OP using `,([0-9]{3}),` to see if a replacement needed to occur, glad to see that you found a solution that works for all cases though.